# Float values in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In web application, i write the code like this :

```
  float f= 659/1024
```

but i am getting the resule in f is 0.0 where it has to be 0.6458 smething

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because both values are integers. Use 659.0/1024 or 659F/1024 instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are dividing two integers, so the result will be 0.
You have to cast the numbers to float:

> float f = (float)659/(float)1024

Comment: _One_ of the numbers will be enough.

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing this because you are performing integer division and then assigning the result to a float. Try the following instead:

```
float f = 659.0 / 1024;
```

Or to be more explicit:

```
float f = (float)659 / 1024;
```

Note that only one of the numbers needs to be a float to make the operation perform floating point arithmetic instead of integer arithmetic.